# Why does matplotlib.pyplot.savefig() mess up image outputs for very large pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix()?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I was trying to compute the `pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix()` values for very large  `pandas.DataFrame()`  (relatively speaking for this specific operation, most libraries either run OOM most of the time or implement a row count check of 50000, see [vaex-scatter](https://vaex.io/docs/api.html?highlight=scatter#vaex.viz.DataFrameAccessorViz.scatter)).

The 'Time series' DataFrame shape I have is `(10000000, 41)`. Every value is either a float or an integer.

**Q1:** So the first thing I would already like to ask is how do I do that memory and space efficiently.

### What I tried for Q1

- I tried to do it typically (like in the examples in the documentation) using matplotlib and `modin.pandas.DataFrames` looping over each pair, so the indexing and operations/calculations I want to do are relatively fast including the `to_numpy()` method. How ever as you might have already seen from the image 1 pair takes 18.1 secs at least and 41x41 pairs are too difficult to handle in my task and I feel there is a relatively faster way of doing things. :)

  [image]
- I tried using the pandas scatter plot function which is also too slow and crashes my memory. This is done using the native `pandas` package and not the `modin.pandas`. This was done by first converting the `modin.pandas.DataFrame` to `pandas.DataFrame` via the private `modin.pandas.DataFrame._to_pandas()` accessor. This approach is too slow too. I stopped waiting after I ran out of memory 1 hour later.
- I tried plotting with vaex. This was the fastest but I ran into other errors which arent related to the question.
- please do not suggest seaborn's pair plot. Tried and it takes around 5 mins to generate a `pairplot()` for a `pandas.DataFrame` of shape `(1000x8)`, also is cantered around pandas.

### Current workaround for Q1 and new Q2

- I am plotting a scatter matrix of all the features sampled 10000 times. so `modin.DataFrame.sample(10000)` since it kind of is okay to view at the general trend but i do not wish to do this if there is a better option.
- Converting it to `pandas.DataFrame` and using `pandas.plotting.scatter_matrix` like this, so that i dont have to wait for it to be rendered onto the jupyter notebook.

```
%%time
# plt.xticks(np.arange(len(dataset.columns)),dataset.columns, rotation = 90)
# plt.yticks(np.arange(len(dataset.columns)),dataset.columns)
axes = scatter_matrix(dataset._to_pandas(), figsize=(512,512))
plt.tight_layout()
plt.savefig('scatter_matrix.jpeg')
```

**Q2:** I am unable to figure out why the rendered image is not correct visually.

#### Samples of the rendered image since file is too large to post here

[image: missed plots]

[image: Phantom Grid]

[image: This is how the grid should look like.]

There are many image artefacts. any suggestions?

Comment: You are asking to put 10 million markers on the screen. That will be quite slow.  `plt.plot(x, y, '.')` will be significantly faster, but its hard to know what the goal of 10 million markers might be.  You may consider methods of reducing your data, and in particular consider using np.histogram2d to make density plots.

Comment: You may also be interested in https://datashader.org for large data sets

Comment: datashader.org, I will try. But I see that it used Dask DataFrames. Yet another DataFrame wrapper I have to learn :( Don't know how anyone else feels but I feel I spend time learning pointless new frameworks/stuff for achieving one specific thing. Is this Datascience?

Comment: @JodyKlymak datashader.org does it effortlessly. Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For future readers, the process I opted was to use [datashader.org](https://datashader.org) as @JodyKlymak suggested in his comment(Thanks) with `pandas.DataFrame`.

please bear in mind that this approach answers both the questions.

1. Convert your `modin.pandas.DataFrame` to `pandas.DataFrame` with the private `modin.pandas.DataFrame._to_pandas()`
2. plot the graphs first to an xarray image like so [xarray-imshow](http://xarray.pydata.org/en/stable/generated/xarray.plot.imshow.html).

```
import datashader as ds
import datashader.transfer_functions as tf

cols = dataset_1.columns
plots = {}
for idx in range(41): # generating 40 plots on the fly
    if idx == 0:
        pass
    else:
        x = cols[idx]
        y = cols[idx-1]
        plots['some_unique_key'] = tf.shade(cvs.points(dataset_1[[x, y]], x, y))

# traverse the dictionary to use the xarray.plot.imshow() 
plots['some_unique_key'].plot.imshow()
```

### Time

```
CPU times: user 723 ms, sys: 43 ms, total: 766 ms
Wall time: 757 ms
```

### Image

[image]